# How do I change the CSS of the default Paragraph Format in Froala Editor?

Tags: css, angular, froala

I'm implementing Froala Editor in an Angular project. I want to be able to change the default Paragraph Format drop down and to be able to apply my own styles to the options in there.

I know there is the [paragraphFormat](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/#paragraphFormat) option where I can change the list in the drop down, but it doesn't mention where I would define the CSS for those options. Anyone have any ideas where/how I can do that? I don't want to use the separate [paragraphSyltes](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/#paragraphStyles) option as that introduces a separate button and doesn't have the paragraphFormatSelection dropdown feature that default paragraph format comes with.

Edit: Thanks for the help, I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nix1016/ay78k4jp/11/) for the problem. Not sure exactly what the CSS should be, this is what I have but doesn't work:

```
.froala-paragraph-drop-down { 
    .H1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: red;
            font-size: 14px; 
    }
}
```

Can you please help me with making Heading 1, say 14px red in both the paragraph dropdown as well as when applied to the text in the editor?

Comment: Most libraries will work if you put your `css` in your global css file.

Comment: Like Kirubel said, the idea is to overwrite the default froala classes in your global css file. In your styles.css, if you want to overwrite the font-size of the class froala-paragraph-drop-down, use: .froala-paragraph-drop-down { font-size: 14px; }. 
If you can provide a stackblitz we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nix1016/ay78k4jp/11/) for it. Can you please help me with making Heading 1, say 14px red in both the paragraph dropdown as well as when applied to the text in the editor?

Comment: I got it! Thanks! Was using .h1 instead of h1.